# Why can't I see the generated project files from my docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, windows-10

I'm very new to docker world. I'm using Docker for desktop and I'm following the quickstart guide on Docker and Rails.

After running:

```sh
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=postgresql
```

I don't see any project files created on my Windows 10 Pro machine directory. I've followed the same tutorial on an Ubuntu machine but it works just fine.

Comment: I'm new to docker to and have seen the same tutorial, I work on a mac so I don't have your same trouble, but I do remember reading somewhere that you had to setup something special to let docker know about windows volume shares, so you may want to investigate that. Also, I have been investigating the --no-deps in that command line and I think it is meant to be after the run and before the rails command, because it is really a docker-compose option, not a rails option. Maybe it doesn't matter, but it is certainly confusing because --no-deps it does not show in the rails new --help

Answer (score 0):

I had my volumes set to

```yaml
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

changing it to

```yaml
    volumes:
      - .:/<the folder im copying too in my DOCKERFILE>
```

worked a treat!